# Trouble with compiling JNI

Tags: java, c, linux, gcc, java-native-interface

I have the following C code implemented by referencing to a header file already generated with JNI:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
     printf("Hello World!\n");
     return;
}
```

When I try to compile it (to generate the so library) using:

```
cc -g -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/include
-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/include/linux HelloWorld.c -o libHelloWorld.so
```

I got this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add the [-shared](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) linker option

First create the object file:

```
cc -c HelloWorld.c
```

Then create the so

```
cc -shared -o libHelloWorld.so HelloWorld.o
```

Comment: I had the same error as the OP. I manage to run the first command properly, however, after running the second command I get this:  /usr/bin/ld: HelloWorld.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
HelloWorld.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Any ideas?

Comment: @hadis you probably need to compile with -fPIC as the error suggest

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 steps to creating an so file:

```
 cc -c test.c
 cc -shared test.o -o test.so
```

Have a look at [Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) for the details.

Answer (score -1):

insert the -shared flag

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -o libmyhello.so -shared HelloWorld.c
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add main function. add

```
int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

, or alternatively `int main(char *argv[], int argc)`

Comment: It's a library; you don't need a main function.