# Building .so file with JNI issue

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, java-native-interface

I have the exact same code as [Trouble with compiling JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829185/trouble-with-compiling-jni/15829349#15829349). In fact, had the same issue. Tried solving using the two step approach, which is running the following:

```
cc -c HelloWorld.c
```

Then the next command:

```
cc -shared -o libHelloWorld.so HelloWorld.o
```

The first one runs find and creates HelloWorld.o, however, after running the second command, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA9BIT2.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC /tmp/ccA9BIT2.o: error adding symbols: Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm running an ubuntu 16.04 and JDK version 8

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the error message, it says *recompile with -fPIC*, so compile it that: `cc -c HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.o -fPIC`.

Comment: Take a look here for simple - "Hello world" - sample. http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/ You can find all the steps there - from sources, through compilation to execution. Have fun with JNI! :)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something like that

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Have fun with JNI! ;) .oOo.

Comment: @Pablo: that worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you start your experience with JNI, it's always good to start with super simple - preferably "Hello world" - sample. This way, you can make sure all the elements in the chain are working as expected.

Start with simple class (it's good idea to put it inside package):

```
package recipeNo001;

public class HelloWorld {

  /* This is the native method we want to call */
  public static native void displayMessage();

  /* Inside static block we will load shared library */
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Call to shared library */
    HelloWorld.displayMessage();
  }
}
```

You will also need native code itself. Make it as simple as possible

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "jni.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo001_HelloWorld_displayMessage
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj) {

  printf("Hello world!\n");

}
```

Note that JNI has a fixed naming convention when it comes to names of the functions: [Resolving Native Method Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#resolving_native_method_names)

Then, you can compile everything:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac -d target java/recipeNo001/HelloWorld.java
```

`-d` means that classes will be compiled inside directory `target`

```
cc -g -shared -fpic -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \ 
  -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/$(ARCH) HelloWorld.c \
  -o lib/libHelloWorld.so
```

Once everything is compiled, you can simply run the sample:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java \
  -Djava.library.path=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:./lib \
  -cp target recipeNo001.HelloWorld
```

Note that we are setting class path with `-cp` because class files were generated inside `target` directory.

That's it :) You can find more samples here: [JNI Cookbook](http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org)

Comment: Thanks for this! When would you suggest using Swig instead of JNI?

Comment: Personally, I am not a fan of Swig and JNA. However, if you know that you will use the very same code from different languages (e.g. Python, Java) I'd consider using it. I don't have much experience, though. I prefer little bit more dirty, very explicit, JNI.